# use не срабатывает при формировании вызова класса

Tags: php, mvc, composer

Помогите пожалуйста кто может, ото уже 3-ий день мучаюсь.

Дело в том, что пишу mvc framework и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В классе `Router` должен динамически вызываться нужный Контроллер на
строке 44, но при динамическом вызове не срабатывает use и поэтому
вылезает ошибка такого вида:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Home' not found in C:\OSPanel\domains\mvctest\core\Router.php:44 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\mvctest\core\bootstrap.php(15): Core\Router::route(Array) #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\mvctest\index.php(12): require('C:\OSPanel\doma...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\mvctest\core\Router.php on line 44".

Но если на 44 строке заменить `$controller` на `Home`, то всё заработает и `use` подхватиться.
Выглядит это так, с такой записью на строке 44 не работает:

```
"$dispatch = new $controller($controller_name, $action);"
```

А вот с такой всё работает:

```
"$dispatch = new Home($controller_name, $action);"
```

Автозагрузчик использую от `composer`.

Ссылка на гит: "https://github.com/shisuich/mvctest"

Ссылка на класс Router: "https://github.com/shisuich/mvctest/blob/master/core/Router.php"

Ссылка на класс Home: "https://github.com/shisuich/mvctest/blob/master/app/controllers/Home.php"

Ссылка на composer.json:
"https://github.com/shisuich/mvctest/blob/master/composer.json"

Comment: Eсли не ошибаюсь, то у Вас лишний слеш в composer.json `            "Controllres\\": "app/controllers"` вместо `            "Controllres\\": "app/controllers/"`

Comment: Всё ровно, не работает хоть так  "Controllres\\": "app/controllers", хоть так "Controllres\\": "app/controllers/"

Comment: попробуйте в Route.php использовать `use Controllres;` без ссылки на конкретный класс

Comment: Не помогло, всё та же ошибка

Comment: курсовая работа что ли? судя по написанию очевидных и бесполезных комментариев.

Comment: Отладьте и посмотрите в автозагрузчике куда он пытается посмотреть чтобы найти ваш контроллер.

Comment: Нет, сам для себя делаю и комментирую

Comment: Кстати, желательно проверять существование класса через `class_exists` И проверьте, что приходит в `$controller`, а хотя вам правильно подметили, что опечатка в коде, может быть в ней и проблема.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Controllres;
```

опечатка в слове `Controllres` >> `Controllers`

Comment: Ошибка не из-за того. Тем не менее в других файлах используется слово `Controllres`, `"Controllres\\": "app/controllers"`.

Answer (score 0):

В $conroller у меня было название контроллера "Home", когда я пытался создать объект класса таким образом:
"$dispatch = new $controller($controller_name, $action);"
И автозагрузчик искал его в глобальном namespace и "use Controller\Home;" не помогал, потому что он не может подхватить класс, когда название класса в переменной.
Помогло следующее, вместо того чтобы передавать в переменную $controller просто название класса "Home", нужно передать ПОЛНОЕ название т.е. c namespace.

Будет работать:

$controller = 'Controllers\Home';

Как-то так

Comment: пользуйся composer для управления автозагрузкой и будет тебе щастя